# How do I maintain more audit history?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, security, audit

I created a SQL Server audit and when I view the audit logs I only see today’s audit. I am saving it to a file and I want to store audit for one year. Is there a way to store database and server audit for one year? Does SQL Server store audits for only a day?

```
CREATE SERVER AUDIT [Audit-20130618-142022] TO FILE 
(
  FILEPATH = N'C:\Documents\Audit\Audit' ,
  MAXSIZE = 0 MB ,
  MAX_ROLLOVER_FILES = 2147483647 ,
  RESERVE_DISK_SPACE = OFF 
) 
WITH 
( 
  QUEUE_DELAY = 1000 ,
  ON_FAILURE = CONTINUE 
);
```

Comment: What's the definition (DDL) of your server audit?  If you could post your `CREATE SERVER AUDIT` command that would be helpful (feel free to make file paths and sensitive information anonymous).

Comment: I selected unlimited for the max file size in the GUI. When I'm generating the script it's setting the maxsize to 0. Is there something wrong with setting maxsize to unlimited?

Comment: I was able to create the audit using the above script. It didn't give any error with the 0 MB file size

Comment: Even though the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280448.aspx) says `Specifying a value lower than 2 MB will raise the error MSG_MAXSIZE_TOO_SMALL.`, I tried using `0 MB` and it does work -- it's interpreted as `UNLIMITED`.

Comment: @Jon yep, I've been trying to add this comment to [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280448.aspx), but keep getting `Error occurred while saving your data`: "I found this quite unintuitive. If I create a server audit with MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, the DDL replaces UNLIMITED with 0 MB (as does SSMS if you use the UI to apply or script it out). Following the documentation, this *should* raise an error, as it's less than the 2 MB minimum. The docs should list this equivalence somewhere."

Comment: @Jon documentation is queued for revision.

Comment: Can you post a screen shot of exactly what you're seeing when you review the audit logs? I have an audit going back a ways and I see plenty of log entries before today. Are you sure that the audit has been enabled the whole time? Are you sure there are audit specifications hooked up to this audit that populate it with events? Are you sure those specifications existed and were enabled prior to today? If you're relying on the most recent `.sqlaudit` file in `C:\Documents\Audit\Audit` you need to look for more `.sqlaudit` files...

Comment: I did enable the both audit and the audit specification a week ago. Each day when I view the log I only see that day's audit logs. Does it create separate audit file (.sqlaudit) each day? I am actually viewing the audit log from the Sql Server Management Studio.

Comment: It did create a separate file. Audit log in the SSMS shows only a day's worth of logs

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to specify the time-span for which audit-files are kept. They are kept based on size and number of rollover files. The old ones will be deleted then. If rollover = 0 and you restart the audit every day, you would only ever have 1 file for example. If you want an "advanced archive mechnanism" you have to store the files elsewhere, i.e. in a special Datawarehouse. (recommended)

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server 2012, the **Create Audit** dialog enables to specify the audit files size and number. You cannot specify the time the times are saved, but the file size and number might be enough to accomplish what you're looking for

**Maximum rollover files** - the number of files kept in the system. When the maximum number is reached, the new files overwrite the oldest ones. The default value is unlimited

**Maximum files** - the number of files kept in the system. When the maximum number is reached, the old files will not be overwritten, and storing new audit information will fail

**Maximum file size (MB)** sets the size of the target file. When the specified size is reached, a new file is created. The default value is unlimited

[image]

[MSDN - CREATE SERVER AUDIT (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280448.aspx)